# Angular 2: Too many components in a module?

Tags: forms, performance, angular

I'm a currently working on a sign up forms, which has multiple steps and various conditional forms depending on the account type. The module has almost 30 components (a mix of children and parent components) and all of these are imported into the module file. This is making the entire Angular 2 site run really slow, especially after navigating to the sign up forms and then to another route.

Is it possible that there are too many components/service/providers in a module that it's impacting the performance of the site negatively? Is it recommended to break down the multi-step sign up application forms to multiple modules?

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

... all the other imports of components/service for this module

export const routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: parentComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    resolve: {
        someData: someDataResolver
    },
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: '0', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: '0', 
            component: someComponent1,
            resolve: {
                someData1: someData1Resolver
            }
        },

        ... a bunch more children routes/components

        { path: '20', 
            component: someComponent20,
            resolve: {
                someData20: someData1Resolver
            }
        }
    ]
}]

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ ... ],
    entryComponents: [ ... ],
    imports: [ ... ],
    providers: [ ... ],
})

export default class SampleModule {
    static routes = routes
}
```

Comment: It is not the definition of `NgModule` that matters the most, it's how you instantiate/use the components. I'm not sure about your definition of 'slow' here but I have similar settings (more than 30 components each module, several modules) and there's no noticeable lag in my application.

Comment: Try switching to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. Ensure you don't have function calls in bindings. Use the profiling tools of your browser to figure out what uses up most CPU resources. 30 components is nothing. A single component that doen't work efficiently can cause more harm then hundreds of components. More simple components are probably better for performance than a single very complex component.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @GünterZöchbauer & @HarryNinh! So, it sounds like there might be something wrong with the components rather than the definitions within the module. I've tested out putting ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush in the components and it didn't seem to make much of a difference. I'll try to explore the components with the profiling tools:)

Comment: @HarryNinh - You mentioned about properly instantiating/using the components. Are you referring to the lifecycle hooks that are used within each component? Do you have any resources/tips that ensure that I am instantiating the components properly?

Answer (score 0):

Components number in a module matters only on first load time(or page refresh), then they are loaded in memory. Look for issue in other place